# what's meaning `asdf env` command of asdf-vm?

Tags: asdf-vm

I have readed the [asdf-vm document](https://asdf-vm.com/manage/commands.html),I can't understand  `asdf env` command.
what's mean util?and what's different between `asdf exec` and `asdf env` ?They seem have the same features?
or `asdf env` just print environment variables?
Could someone tell me ?or give some article or give a example.
Thanks!

Please give me some article or some example